# Django admin: inline model: how to access current record id from has_delete_permission method

Tags: django, model, admin, inline

Django 2.2

**admin.py**, the background and the question are basically inlined in the code:

```
class ProductAdmin(<SomeSuperAdmin>)
   inlines = [
       ProductCommentInline,
   ]
   # blah-blah...

class ProductCommentAdmin(<SomeSuperAdmin>):
   # blah-blah...

class ProductCommentInline(admin.TabularInline):  
    model = ProductComment

   # blah-blah...

    #this is called for each record in my queryset of ProductComments,
    # and depending on one field value I want it to return True or False
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        #here I have obj.id which is id of Product, but not ProductComment

        #here I need to get somehow current ProductComment record data
        product_comment_record = <get_somehow_current_record_data >
        return product_comment_record.<some_bool_field>
```

**How do I access a current ProductComment record data from has_delete_permission method of an inline model?**

I realize I have the whole ProductComment Queryset:

```
all_productcomments_records = self.get_queryset(request).filter(product_id=obj.id),
```

but I need to access the **current** record data. I did not ind anything in `self` or `request`

Comment: @bhaskarc Not sure what you mean, I am using TabularInline. That link does not address the question of marking specific records of an inline queryset certain way, just explains how to filter it. I don't want to filter anything out, I want to treat them differently.  And it's from almost 8 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

OK, what worked for me at the end is the (somewhat adapted) answer by [Benoit Blanchon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1164966/benoit-blanchon) at this post: [Django Admin - how to prevent deletion of some of the inlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467848/django-admin-how-to-prevent-deletion-of-some-of-the-inlines). It gave me access to the `index` which is the variable I was after.

```
from django.forms.models import BaseInlineFormSet

class ProductCommentInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    # set "delete" checkbox to grayed out state for already deleted (is_active=False)
    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        super().add_fields(form, index)
        form.fields['DELETE'].disabled = False
        if index != None:
            try:
                if not self.get_queryset()[index].is_active:
                    form.fields['DELETE'].disabled = True
            except:
                pass

class ProductCommentInline(admin.TabularInline): 
    model = ProductComment

    formset = ProductCommentInlineFormSet
```